# How to deal with Region cookie corrupted for region 0x160800000

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I keep getting this memory issue during my programs runtime it keeps happening in different sections of the code. Most often when destructors are called

`gp_train_main(68648,0x1d9095ec0) malloc: Region cookie corrupted for region 0x160800000 (value is 0)[0x16080407c]`

p.s. this is the line where i often encounter the ussue

https://github.com/amantham20/CSE491_GP_Group7/blob/cf69087fb2e5ed07777d88d6b283767045d09c08/source/Agents/GP/GPTrainingLoop.hpp#L615

I have tried using valgrind to narrow down the issue but have failed to.
I have partially tried the mem sanitizer from LLVM.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to say anything more specific than "something in your code is writing to memory where it shouldn't be writing".

Comment: please show a [mre], note that the corruption likely didn't occur where your program is crashing